# How to export a Unity terrain to a DEM or other 3d data for external use?

Tags: unity, terrain, data, export

I have found numerous examples of exporting Unity terrain to programs like Blender or just importing digital elevation files (DEMs) into Unity. But can a terrain generated in Unity be exported into software like QGIS or as just a DEM?

I was given a fictional Unity terrain (it did not originate from a DEM or any external data) for a scientific simulation but in order to create some additional code, I need to do some external analysis on that terrain in R, python, or MATLAB. Is this a possibility? How would one go about it?

Comment: Presumably you considered using [the TerrainData API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.html) like the `GetHeights()` method to iterate over the heightmap values in the terrain and transform/save them into any format you like? Where did you run into difficulty doing this transformation?

Comment: I have not considered it. As I said, someone gave me the Unity terrain; I do not know how to use Unity, so I was looking for some sort of tutorial or guide to walk me through it.

Comment: Right now your question as phrased will only draw answers from users who are familiar with *both* Unity and QGIS/DEM file formats, and have time to walk you through the whole thing - that's a tall order and can make it slow to get good answers. If it's just the Unity part you need help with, consider editing your question to include a description of the output file you want to generate. That way it can be answered by any user with Unity experience, even if they didn't know the target file format details before reading your question.

Comment: It seems that a [raster format DEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model#Types) is essentially a grid based height map. Is that version acceptable? If so, that would be good info to include as it simplifies the problem. Would simply dumping the heightmap data into a CSV file might be good enough?

Comment: I think a CSV file would be something I could work with. So far I have been able to use the terrain toolbox to create a *.raw heightmap file, but I don't know how to access/convert the data contained therein.

Comment: When you want to add information to your question, don't forget to click the **Edit** link to add it there. This bumps your question to the top of the feed. Otherwise, your remarks in comments are likely to go unnoticed.